# Looping in Sql to insert data in to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL statement:

```
select 
    tms.Team, Count(tms.MSApprovedNPC) as JulyNPCResults 
from 
    tmsorder2 tms
where 
    Msapprovednpc not in ('N/A','No') and Month(Month) = 11 and Year(month) = '2013'
group by 
    tms.Team
```

these results are for a specific month of July 2013.

Now I want to load the results in a table NPRData for other months in to one table which has columns like

```
TEAM, JulyNPRResults, AugNPRResults, SepNPRResults, OctNPRResults
```

How can I loop the above query to insert data for other months?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to loop rather than insert all of them?

Comment: As i have multiple months to insert in to NPRData i need to Loop the above query for all the months rt?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against storing your data in a denormalized format. It would be better to have a table like:

```
NPRData (Team,YearMonth,Results)
```

But you can do this without looping via a conditional `SUM()` or `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT tms.Team
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Month)=11 and YEAR(month) ='2013' THEN 1 END) As NovNPRResults
     ,SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(Month)=12 and YEAR(month) ='2013' THEN 1 END) As DecNPRResults
FROM tmsorder2 tms
WHERE Msapprovednpc NOT IN ('N/A','No') 
GROUP BY tms.Team
```